# CakePHP - Login collision

Tags: cakephp, authentication, collision

I'm working on some projects (all in CakePHP) and I found an issue. The problem is that when I'm logged in one system and I try to log into another one with SAME USERNAME, it logs me in to the second one and logs me out of the first one. The problem only appears when I try it with same user name. I have different Security.salt and Security.cipherSeed variables.

Can anyone help me ? Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you using the same Session Name in all your apps?

Edit:

What about the cookie name? Maybe you are using the same name and same domain, thus every time you login you rewrite the cookie. I would change the name of the cookie in every app. 
Edit your core.php

```
Configure::write('Session.cookie', "app1");//app2, app3, etc
```

Comment: Probably yes. I'm not sure what you mean by Session Name but if it's name of Session variable, probably yes. I haven't changed any session setting in app

Answer (score 0):

You can set session path for different project in **AppContoller** or **UsersController**

```
function beforeFilter() {

$this->Session->path = '/projectname/';

}
```

So, Each time session path will be different for different project and not conflict in Login process

Comment: I tried this in both App ans Users controllers and it didn't work. But solution above works. But thank you for your help !